# Downloading file From Server and saving it to Local Storage but not able to use that File

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am downloading Audio or video or .png or pdf file from Server.Example i downloading audio file from that but not able to play that file i think it is Encoded .File Are Stored In DropBox. In responseBody Coming Like this 000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\
i can download it not able to play that file .actually file size 434Kb but its showing 2.3MB

Here is the Code

```
   ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient();
                    RestClient restClientAPI = apiClient.getClient();
                    Call<ResponseBody> call = restClientAPI.downloadFileWithFixedUrl(listStudentRes.get(fragmentListner.getAppPreferenceHelper().getTopTitlePosition()).getOrgId(),datumArrayList.get(Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString())).getFileName());
                    call.enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<ResponseBody>()
                    {
                        @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                            Log.d("Response : ",""+response.body());
                            Log.d("ResponseContLength : ",""+response.body().contentLength());


                               String directoryName = "ValaiSchool Audio";
                            File myDir;
                            if (!directoryName.equals("")) {
                                myDir = new File(ctx.getExternalFilesDir(ctx.getString(R.string.app_name)), directoryName);
                            } else {
                                myDir = new File(ctx.getExternalFilesDir(ctx.getString(R.string.app_name)), null);
                            }

                            if (!myDir.exists()) {
                                myDir.mkdirs();
                            }
                            File outputFile = new File(myDir, datumArrayList.get(Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString())).getFileName());
                            Log.d("outputFile",""+outputFile);
                            try {
                                FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

                                InputStream inputStream = response.body().byteStream();
                                Log.d("inputStream",""+inputStream);

                                totalSize =response.body().contentLength();

                                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024*1024];

                                int bufferLength;

                                long total = 0;
                                while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                                    total += bufferLength;
                                    fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                                     Log.d("Downloading",""+( (int)((total*100)/totalSize)));

                                }

                                fileOutput.flush();
                                if (fileOutput != null) {
                                    fileOutput.close();
                                }
                                if (inputStream != null) {
                                    inputStream.close();
                                }

                            } catch (final MalformedURLException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Log.e("MalformedURLException", "MalformedURLException>>" + e.getMessage());

                            } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Log.e("ProtocolException", "ProtocolException>>" + e.getMessage());

                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Log.e("IOException", "IOException>>" + e.getMessage());

                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                             Log.d("Error",""+t);
                        }
                    });



                } else {
                    circularFileDownload.showMessage();
                }
```

Retrofit interface :

```
 @Streaming
@GET("./Dropbox/fileDownload")
Call<ResponseBody> downloadFileWithFixedUrl(@Header("org_id") Integer org_id ,@Header("File_Name") String File_Name);
```

Comment: does your file name contains file extension type too ?

Comment: No.what is File Extension?

Comment: Like .mp3 or .mp4?

Comment: As you said you can image,video,audio anything, so you should have appropriate file extension too like png for image,mp4 for audio etc

Comment: Yes ,it contains.i can able to download but not able to play it

Comment: For verifying download the file directly from dropbox and then try to play it

Comment: i did it's playing

Comment: Can you show your dropbox url

Comment: do we have to Decode the file?

Comment: https://valaischool.com/api/Dropbox/fileDownload

Comment: This is not a direct dropbox url,confirm this from the developer who developed this api whether they have used any encoding or not

Comment: he said he did not encode but Response is  showing like this 000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000